# az storage account: 'blob-service-properties' is not in the 'az storage account' command group

Tags: azure, azure-cli

I want to enable versioning, Change Feed in Azure storage account using CLI. I got the below command from the Microsoft document https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cli/azure/storage/account/blob-service-properties?view=azure-cli-latest.

```
    az storage account blob-service-properties update -n sdffsjhiwezzaz --enable-change-feed true --enable-versioning true --enable-delete-retention true --delete-retention-days 100
```

And got the below error

```
    az storage account: 'blob-service-properties' is not in the 'az storage account' command group. See 'az storage account --help'.
```

Kindly tell me how to enable versioning and ChangeFeed using Azure CLI

Answer (score 1):

I am using azure-cli 2.27.1 and found that this worked.  No the syntax is slightly different

```
az storage blob service-properties update --account-name mystorageaccount --delete-retention true --delete-retention-period 5
```

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cli/azure/storage/blob/service-properties?view=azure-cli-latest#az_storage_blob_service_properties_update

Answer (score 0):

I am able to run the command successfully. Please ensure that you have the latest version of CLI installed.

When I run `az --version` command, this is what I see:

```
azure-cli                          2.2.0

command-modules-nspkg              2.0.3
core                               2.2.0
nspkg                              3.0.4
telemetry                          1.0.4
```

Also for change feed, you will need to register your subscription for this feature as it is currently in preview. You can find instructions about it here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/storage/blobs/storage-blob-change-feed?tabs=azure-portal#register-your-subscription-preview.